# Not returning desired error/success message

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason when I submit my form what gets submitted back is "There was a problem creating the user! Please try again!" but it still makes a new database entry and I'm not sure why. I'm running tests on my form but with the data I'm submitting it should be giving me a success message. Any ideas?

EDIT: I've tried for 2 days now and still can't seem to figure this out.

**Controller:**

```
function register_submit()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|alpha_numeric|strtolower');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|matches[password]|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|alpha');  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|alpha');    

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!'));    
    }
    else
    {                           
        $user_data = $this->kow_auth->create_user($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'), $this->input->post('first_name'), $this->input->post('last_name'));
        if ($user_data == FALSE)      
        {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'There was a problem creating the user! Please try again!'));
        }     
        else
        {
            $data['activation_period'] = 48;
            $this->kow_auth->send_email('activate', $data['email'], $data);
            unset($data['password']);   
            echo json_encode(array('sucess' => 'yes', 'message' => 'You have successfully registered. Check your email address to activate your account!'));
        }
    }
}
```

**Library:**

```
/**
 * Create new user on the site and return some data about it:
 * user_id, username, password, email, new_email_key (if any).
 *
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  array
 */
function create_user($username, $email, $password, $first_name, $last_name)
{
    if ((strlen($username) > 0) AND !$this->ci->users->is_username_available($username)) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    } 
    elseif (!$this->ci->users->is_email_available($email)) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $genPassHash = $this->ci->genfunc->GenPassHash($password);

        $max_user_id = $this->ci->users->get_max_users_id();

        $data = array(
            'username'      => $username,
            'password'      => $genPassHash[0],
            'password2'     => $genPassHash[1],
            'email'         => $email,
            'first_name'    => $first_name,
            'last_name'     => $first_name,
            'new_email_key' => md5(rand().microtime()),
            'user_id'       => $max_user_id,
            'ip_address'    => $this->ci->input->ip_address()
        );

        if (($result = $this->ci->users->create_user($data)) == FALSE)
        {
            $data['user_id'] = $res['user_id'];
            $data['password'] = $password;
            unset($data['last_ip']);
            return $data;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

**Users Model:**

```
/**
 * Create new user record
 *
 * @param   array
 * @return  bool
 */
function create_user($data)
{
    $data['date_created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $this->db->set('username', $data['username']); 
    $this->db->set('password', $data['password']); 
    $this->db->set('password2', $data['password2']); 
    $this->db->set('email', $data['email']);
    $this->db->set('first_name', $data['first_name']);  
    $this->db->set('last_name', $data['last_name']); 
    $this->db->set('ip_address', $data['ip_address']); 
    $this->db->set('date_created', $data['date_created']); 

    $query = $this->db->insert('users');

    if ($query) 
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well whatever is in user_data it doesn't == FALSE. So may be echo user_data to see what is in there would help you out.

Comment: Right, if the data is entered properly and fully as expected, but you are reporting an error, the best bet is checking your creation and evaluation of the return value

Comment: I did an echo and print_r right after it and nothing is there. So that doesn't help.

Comment: Nothing != FALSE, so it confirms the issue. I suspect if you reversed your logic (!= TRUE) it would never fail. :( You'll have to follow it back to where you do get false and then suss out what is trampling on your result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some sql errors at some point in all those inserts and $query is FALSE, you should read about transactions to avoid this partial inserts ... it's about logic mostly . Basicaly you don't want to perfprm any inserts if any of the inserts in your logic will fail so go and read about transactions. You didnt specified what db platform your using so i can't give a sure link ... if your using mysql here is a link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html